# executeUpdate without commit in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc

I have a class named GenericService which has annotated with

`@Transactional(readOnly = false)`

and another class extends from GenericService named ExtendedService. In ExtendedService I have a method annotated with

`@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW, readOnly = true)`

which calls save method and update method. so far the save method works fine, I mean it validates the object to be saved with `@NotNull` but it doesn't commit it, otherwise the update method executed update query and neglect `readOnly = true`. What seems to be the problem?

Comment: Read the documentation of readOnly. It doesn't do what you think it does. Calling save() and update() from a readOnly method is a problem on your side: you shouldn't do that, otherwise the method is not readOnly anymore. Accessing the same entity from two different transactions is also something you should not do.

Comment: Well, do you have any ideas? what should I do to not commit the update query?

Comment: Don't do it in the first place. Why execute an update query if you don't want any update to happen? What are you trying to achieve exactly?

Comment: You know, It's a general service. In some cases the transaction should be committed and in other cases, the hibernate only needs to validate the entity for save without commit, then we wait for other information from user.

Comment: Hibernate is an ORM. Not a validator. You shouldn't use Hibernate to validate your entities. Hibernate does use bean validation internally to validate the entities before saving, but that doesn't mean you must save entities to validate them. Just use the bean validation API yourself if you want to do that. What you're doing is basically equivalent to sending a letter to see if you put enough stamps on it, instead of just weighing the letter and check by yourself.